# Problems integrating drupal-ios-sdk with iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, drupal, drupal-modules

I downloaded the Drupal-iOS-SDK from [github](https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk)
and I also downloaded AFNetworking files [from here](https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk).

Then I added the files to my project, but it shows a strange error

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSInteger, NSInteger, NSInteger)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSInteger, long long, long long)'

for this piece of code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];
```

Does anyone have any idea what this means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending three `NSInteger`s as parameters to `setUploadProgressBlock` when it's expected one `NSUInteger` (unsigned integer) and two `long long` parameters

`totalBytesWritten` and `totalBytesExpectedToWrite` need to be of type `long long` because that's how they are defined, not `NSInteger's. Your piece of code should look like:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
```

You may also want to modify your NSLog accordingly now that it's set to `long long` so the compiler doesn't complain.

```
NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
```

Comment: I have just tried it out and now it gives a similar error: Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSInteger, long long, long long)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSInteger, long long, long long)'

Comment: I've updated my code a bit, make sure you do a clean and build and are definitely using the LLVM compiler for your project and target

Comment: I cleaned my solution and did as you ask, it only removes the warning from the NSLog but still it shows the error. Maybe you should go to the Drupal-iOS-SDK link above and integrate it in a blank project. Just build it to see why you get such errors. Thanks!

Comment: It seems it also wants the NSInteger to be of type NSUInteger (Unsigned Integer) for it to work. I've amended my code above

Comment: Thanks a lot, build succeeded :D